# How can i render html website in nativescript application?

Tags: html, mobile, nativescript

How can I render html and/or non local website into a `nativescript` app? I cant find a way to start or manipulate a browser instance.

Comment: http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/web-view/WebView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/web-view/HOW-TO.html) will help you quite a bit, but here are two examples:

**Example with url**

This example will create a new page with a WebView on it and then navigate to that page. Url may be local (html file on phone) or remote (http://...)

```
var frameModule = require('ui/frame');
var pageModule = require('ui/page');
var webViewModule = require("ui/web-view");

var factoryFunc = function () {
    var webView = new webViewModule.WebView();
    webView.url = 'http://www.example.com';
    var page = new pageModule.Page();
    page.content = webView;
    return page;
};

frameModule.topmost().navigate(factoryFunc);
```

**Example of loading local data into a WebView**

An example of where you have a view (`.xml`) and and its corresponding `.js` file and where you feed it a string containing the html to be displayed.

Where the `.xml` is:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded">
    <WebView id="myWebView" />
</Page>
```

and the `.js`:

```
exports.loaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var webView = page.getViewById('myWebView');
    var application = require('application');
    var html = '<html><body><h1>I can haz webview?</h1></body><html>';

    if (application.ios) {
        webView.ios.loadHTMLStringBaseURL(html, null);
    } else if (application.android) {
        webview.android.loadData(html, 'text/html', null);
    }
};
```

Comment: i try to run this example and the android emulator starts the app, it pop-ups me a message "Unfortunately , myapp has stopped. "

p.s. i used the url example so im not pretty sure about my xml file and what it is supposed to contain

Comment: maybe is smthin wrong with my permissions?....i cant figure out what is wrong by the logs

Comment: Does your logs say anything? Can you show your code?

Comment: As Vlad said in a comment (which my low reputation prohibits me to comment on), you can use the src property. It's not yet released but you can checkout the code from GitHub and build it. Follow the _Using the latest tns_modules_ steps here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/180

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming release you will be able to specify the HTML like this:

```
<Page>
    <WebView src="<html><body><h1>I can haz webview?</h1></body><html>" />
</Page>
```

Src property will work for URL and local file path as well.

Comment: do you know when the the release will come ?

Comment: The release will be in early June you can however get the latest from master branch even now. Here is also more info about running latest from master: http://docs.nativescript.org/running-latest

Comment: Totally works for me, when not surrounded by <Page></Page>!! Also: <WebView src="http\://whatever"></WebView>; .. (not nested within <Page></Page>) for including HTML by fetching it via the URL. Enjoy, and vote up! :)